# Unit tests very slow because spring classpath scanning scans multiple times the same package

Tags: java, spring, unit-testing, junit, spring-data

Using Spring 3 with spring data, I have a package com.company.repository with all classes related to spring data repository (about 50 classes).

The component scan is declared as :

```
<context:component-scan base-package="com.company"/>
```

In my unit tests, the step to scan spring components is very long (about 10 seconds).
After enabled the trace log, I noted that the package "com.company.repository" is scanned multiple times.
In fact, the method ClassPathScanningCandidateComponentProvider.findCandidateComponents("com.company.repository") is called several times with the same value.
I don't understand why I have this behaviour.
And I don't override it by a custom implementation (or I don't find how to do that).
And I don't understand why the is no cache in the default implementation ?

Someone have an idea why I have this behaviour ? Is it normal ?

In complement, the following is the stack related to my case :

```
ClassPathScanningCandidateComponentProvider.findCandidateComponents(String) line: 224   
RepositoryBeanDefinitionBuilder.detectCustomImplementation(BeanDefinitionRegistry, ResourceLoader) line: 154    
RepositoryBeanDefinitionBuilder.registerCustomImplementation(BeanDefinitionRegistry, ResourceLoader) line: 116  
RepositoryBeanDefinitionBuilder.build(BeanDefinitionRegistry, ResourceLoader) line: 97  
RepositoryBeanDefinitionParser.registerGenericRepositoryFactoryBean(RepositoryConfiguration<XmlRepositoryConfigurationSource>, ParserContext) line: 101 
RepositoryBeanDefinitionParser.parse(Element, ParserContext) line: 71   
JpaRepositoryNameSpaceHandler(NamespaceHandlerSupport).parse(Element, ParserContext) line: 73   
BeanDefinitionParserDelegate.parseCustomElement(Element, BeanDefinition) line: 1419 
BeanDefinitionParserDelegate.parseCustomElement(Element) line: 1409 
DefaultBeanDefinitionDocumentReader.parseBeanDefinitions(Element,  BeanDefinitionParserDelegate) line: 184  
...
XmlBeanDefinitionReader.doLoadBeanDefinitions(InputSource, Resource) line: 390
```

Comment: I wouldn't call it a unit test if you are relying on Spring to create your beans. That sounds more like integration tests.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe your tests are configured to create and destroy your spring context after each test. 
Check your tests base configuration.

Comment: This is the case even for 1 test only.

Comment: After some investigation, I noted that the startup time is very long to register the entire repository classes. So I wanted to exclude with a custom filter some repository classes I don't need for my test. But the "RepositoryBeanDefinitionBuilder" bean doesn't take into account my filter.

I noted that there are 2 different scanners at spring startup : ClassPathScanningCandidateComponentProvider => My filter is taken into account RepositoryComponentProvider => My filter is not taken into account. How I can exclude classes from the second provider (RepositoryComponentProvider) ?

Comment: can you try to remove from component scan your repository package? and specify this path in scan repositories option.

Comment: I can exclude my repository path from component scan. but how I can specify this path in scan repositories option ?

Comment: there is an anotation that specify jpa repositories. **<jpa:repositories base-package="com.acme.repositories" />**

Comment: Effectively, it works with an exclude filter in <jpa:repositories>. I can exclude some repo that I don't need. And this is why I have two different scan. One scan with component-scan and one with <jpa:repositories>. Thank you Duardito